# FreeBSD: Directory called ^C (really!) - how to remove?

Tags: filesystems, freebsd

I made a typo:

```
$ history
169 9:34    la /usr/local/etc/
170 9:35    sudo mkdir ^C
171 9:36    sudo mkdir /usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.d
```

Now I have a file that is called ^C (ctrl+C)!!
When I use `ls` I just see a questionmark (probably due to the locale?)

```
% ls -al
total 60
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   wheel    512 Jan 21 09:35 ?        <- this one
drwxr-xr-x  5 admin  wheel    512 Jan 21 16:24 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   wheel    512 Jan 20 14:29 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 admin  nobody  1114 Jan 20 19:10 .cshrc
-rw-------  1 admin  wheel   6002 Jan 21 15:27 .history
-rw-r--r--  1 admin  nobody   182 Jan 20 14:29 .login
-rw-r--r--  1 admin  nobody    91 Jan 20 14:29 .login_conf
-rw-------  1 admin  nobody   301 Jan 20 14:29 .mail_aliases
-rw-r--r--  1 admin  nobody   271 Jan 20 19:04 .mailrc
-rw-r--r--  1 admin  nobody   726 Jan 20 19:05 .profile
-rw-------  1 admin  nobody   212 Jan 20 14:29 .rhosts
-rw-r--r--  1 admin  nobody   911 Jan 20 19:06 .shrc
drwx------  2 admin  nobody   512 Jan 20 15:05 .ssh
drwxr-xr-x  2 admin  wheel    512 Jan 20 19:08 bin
```

and

```
% ls -i
3611537 ?   3611534 bin
```

I want to remove this file. I try `mv` and when using tab-completion it shows me:

```
% mv
^C/  bin/
```

Obviously I can't type a ^C :-/
How do I remove this file?

Comment: It's too bad that [dsw](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-6th/1/dsw) didn't make it into POSIX.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: too bad [the *original* `dsw`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/LG/issue49/fischer.html) didn't make it into POSIX.

Comment: I don't think you named it ctrl+C, you named it after the ascii character that is mapped to that keyboard shortcut, i.e. ETX (ascii 3) probably. Your console font has no glyph for that character, so it uses a generic substitution glyph "?".

Comment: `emacs -nw -f dired` gives a directory navigator.  <kbd>D</kbd> deletes the file under the cursor after confirmation.

Comment: @MatteoItalia It's too bad control characters in filenames and other [_idiotic_](https://www.dwheeler.com/essays/fixing-unix-linux-filenames.html#control)  ideas made it into POSIX...

Comment: While this may be resolved, personally I use the ls -ld command to verify that I have the right file. As in "ls -ld ./\^C". If that returns the name of the directory I either change the ls -l to rmdir or rm -rf depending on whether the directory contains files or not. I'm hesitant to do deletes with wild cards or finds until I know what would get deleted. Overall this should be a minor issue.

Comment: one way to type a control character is to proceed the char with a control v, similar to:`<ctrl-v><ctrl-c>`

Comment: @user3629249 : you summarized the accepted answer very well. ;)

Comment: This has become my favorite name for new folders now.

Answer (score 192, accepted):

`^V` (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>) works as a kind of escape sequence for the next key-press, inserting the associated value instead of taking whatever action that would normally be associated.

Making use of this, `^V^C` (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>) ought to work for entering your difficult filename in the terminal.

Comment: This was probably how OP made their typo in the first place. V and C are right next to each other on the keyboard.

Comment: Or they were trying to use the Windows clipboard on the bsd terminal.

Comment: @JoelCoel habits never die!

Comment: Interestingly, `^V^C` does *not* work in the Zsh line editor; the [quoted-insert](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html) widget (search the page for `^V`) explicitly does not insert interrupt characters. Jakob's answer (using printf) may be a more portable way of supplying a control character in a shell argument.

Comment: @StigHemmer: What can also happen is you press Ctrl-C in the middle of a command, then forget about this and copy-paste the command later.

Answer (score 92):

You may also remove the file by inode:

```
$ ls -i1
290742 foo
293246 ^C
$ find . -inum 293246 -delete
```

Whatever you do, for God's sake, do not put `-delete` before `-inum`:

```
$ touch foo bar baz quux
$ find . -name '*u*' -delete
$ ls
bar baz foo
$ find . -delete -name 'b*'
find: `./baz': No such file or directory
find: `./bar': No such file or directory
$ ls
$
```

Congratulations, you just wiped out *all* your files. **With `find`, *argument order matters*!**

Comment: Why not put `-delete` before `-inum`? Is this just a precaution in case you press enter prematurely or does the order of the arguments actually affect the outcome?

Comment: @detuur: order affects outcome. See edit.

Comment: Do not put `-delete` into the command, period, until you've run the command without `-delete` to check that it's finding what you want.

Comment: @Kaz will not help much with adding -delete in the center of command

Comment: @RiaD Well, At least find it more natural to add new arguments the end of a changed command instead of in the middle, So it won't prevent it but it might Make it less likely naturally

Comment: @Kaz using `-print` instead of `-delete` makes a very good test.

Comment: Why not ``-exec rmdir``? That would prevent non-empty directories from being deleted.

Comment: @JonasWielicki Certainly a consideration. Going the other direction, `delete` is built in, whereas [`exec` spawns a new process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/167824/50240). That overhead may be problematic in some scenarios.

Comment: Why would find execute arguments as they are read rather than build a complete query before running its action commands?

Comment: @HankCa: `find` doesn't really make any distinction between "query" and "action" subexpressions. `-delete` and `-print` are functions that always return `true` and just happen to have some side effect; this allows to build arbitrary complex expressions. It's a bit like asking "why in C `!unlink(filename) && strcmp(filename,"temp.txt")==0` always deletes `filename`" - well you wrote your expression in reverse, it's not the language fault to do what you asked for. OTOH, given how many files have died due to misconceptions about `find` workings, maybe its interface *could* be more user friendly.

Answer (score 32):

Another option is to use `rm -ri ./*`; `rm` will ask you before deleting any file and directory, so you just need to reply `y` to the "bad" file, and `n` to all the others.

Actually, in your case you can even cut down the number of replies needed by doing `rm -ri ./?`, as your "bad" file is just one character long.

Comment: `select f in ?; do rm -i "$f"; break; done` has all the benefits of `-i`, without the agony of having to answer `no` to leading undesirables or mistakenly answering yes to one you want to keep.

Comment: In the OP's case it's a directory, not a file.  `rmdir ?/` will remove all empty single-character directories, and complain about the others being non-empty.

Comment: @bishop: whoa, I didn't even know that `select` existed, pretty neat!

Comment: @PeterCordes: wops, I didn't notice that we were talking about directories; I added `-r` (and `./` - it's always easy to forget) to my examples, as unfortunately `rmdir` doesn't support the `-i` flag. Still, I suppose that in this case the best way to go would be a combination of bishop's and your comment.

Comment: @MatteoItalia `select` only exists in some shells, which is probably why you haven't run into it - scripts and solutions that are meant to be portable avoid it, so we're less likely to see it "in the wild".

Comment: @mtraceur: yep, in fact I did notice that it's not available in my beloved `fish` :-( oh well, in this case it's powerful globbing would supply.

Comment: @MatteoItalia heh, good thing your username makes your typo of “w**ho**ops” seem less like [some other word](https://wiktionary.org/wiki/wop)

Comment: @can-ned_food: w*ho*ops, of course it was a typo, I didn't mean to offend anybody. OTOH, as UrbanDictionary testifies, almost any letter combination can be interpreted as some form of sexual innuendo and/or racial slur, so I guess I have to come to terms with the fact that inadvertently writing some bad word is pretty much an intrinsic risk of writing anything at all.

Answer (score 23):

One option is to look up the file name with something other than `ls`. If you know it was produced by a verbatim <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, you can find the ASCII character produced using a [table of control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Control_characters), or with a more friendly interface like the one provided by Python:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.listdir('.')
['\x03', ...]
```

Another option would be to look at a hex dump of the output of `ls`, using e.g. [`hexdump`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=hexdump&sektion=1).

Then you can delete the file with (for example) this bash command:

```
rmdir "$(printf '\x03')"
```

(The double quotes are only needed if the character you're trying to print is in your `IFS` variable, such as `\x20` or `\x0A`, but it's a good habit to quote command substitutions unless you know you want the shell to perform field splitting, etc.)

Comment: Also `cat -v` (plus `man ascii`) can help for the first part.

Comment: ... or you use `os.rmdir('\x03')` directly from the Python shell.

Answer (score 15):

Often in this kind of situations it is easy to come up with a **wildcard pattern** that matches the relevant file.

In your case, this would be simply `?` (matching all file names with precisely one character).

Just check that it really matches what you want:

```
ls -ld ?
```

And then remove the directory:

```
rmdir ?
```

---

You can also combine this with **tab completion**. You can type

```
rmdir ?
```

and press tab, and e.g. in bash it will be replaced by

```
rmdir ^C/
```

and you can then hit enter and it does what you want.

Answer (score 11):

You can use Midnight Commander (mc) to delete the file - just select with up/down buttons and press F8.

I did that occasionally when file names had strange characters due to encoding.

Comment: Or just about any other file manager.

Comment: @StigHemmer of course, some do better than others for displaying certain filenames.  Probably the answer could explain why MC is an optimal choice compared to a few select others.  I wouldn't know, as I've never used it.

Answer (score 7):

Yet another way: use `stat` to get an escaped representation of the directory name:

```
$ stat *|grep File:
  File: ‘\003’
```

Now you know a representation of the file name, so you can remove the file by name using `printf`:

```
$ rmdir -v "$(printf '\003')"
rmdir: removing directory, ‘\003’
```

Or, if you're using bash, you can avoid `printf`:

```
$ rmdir -v $'\003'
rmdir: removing directory, ‘\003’
```

Comment: BTW if the shell is bash, `$'\x03'` is simpler than calling printf. The same for FreeBSD sh that is extended over POSIX shell with some tasty features.

Comment: @Netch good point about bash's `$'...'`, but I'd avoid useless conversion from octal to hexadecimal in general. E.g. what if the file were named `'\111'` (in `stat` output)? Would you still remove it using `$'\x49'`? Better use the same sequence as `stat` gave you: in the OP's case, `rmdir $'\003'`.

Answer (score 6):

A solution that has worked for me is:

```
rm ./[Tab][Tab][Tab]...
```

to cycle through the available files until I find the one I want to remove.

But you do need to have the [necessary settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179642/how-can-i-make-bash-tab-completion-behave-like-vim-tab-completion-and-cycle-thro) in your shell for that to work.

Comment: ^C is really early in the tab sequence so +1 for you.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to move everything to the temporary directory and then `rm -r DIRNAME`.

Comment: Does this really seem easier to you than the accepted answer?

Comment: @chicks: It's actually not such a bad answer. I've seen ^V^C not work so somebody might get stuck.

Comment: It isn't wrong per se, but it seems like a lot of extra work compared to the more direct solutions.  Maybe I'm spoiled by Linux, but `^v` has worked consistently me for ages.

Comment: @chicks `^V` need a specific knowledge while moving files around and removal of parent directory can be derived from basics.

Comment: Ctrl+V is dangerously ambigous depending on your exact working environment ... some terminal emulators could interpret it as a paste. If your paste buffer contains the name of something you do not want to delete - and a newline, you could be looking at a problem.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the only empty directory (or you don't care about removing other empty directories), **use `rmdir */`**.  You will get error messages from `rmdir` about not being able to remove non-empty directories, but that's fine.  GNU `rmdir` supports `--ignore-fail-on-non-empty`, or you could `2>/dev/null`.

The trailing `/` makes the glob only match directory names.

You can check ahead of time what empty directories exist under the current one using
`find -maxdepth 1 -type d -empty -ls`.  (And you can change the `-ls` to `-delete` if you want).

You could use a more-specific glob expression like `rmdir [^A-Za-z0-9._]/` to match directories that start with a non-alphanumeric or underscore filename.  I also included `.`, but glob expressions don't match `.` normally anyway.

---

As others have pointed out, you can limit it to single-character names with a glob of `?`:  **`rmdir ?/`**

`rmdir` doesn't have a `-i` option the way `rm` does, presumably because empty directories are usually not valuable and can just be recreated.

Comment: You'd want to know which directories you want to recreate, and `rmdir` can tell you if you pass `-v` option to it (at least in GNU).

Comment: @Ruslan: Not if you had other stale directories you no longer cared about, and removing them would be a bonus.  You could look for empty directories with `find -maxdepth 1 -type d -empty -ls`

Answer (score -1):

Before doing anything risky, try this first:

```
rmdir -- ^C
```

In general -- is a delimiter telling the command no -o ptions will follow, but it will also allow for weird characters to be not interpreted as something else.

Another usage example is `whois -r -- "-r OBJECT-RIPE"`

(-r is a shortcut for ripe, but in the ripe whois also a parameter)

If it doesn't work at first try, then maybe try `rmdir -- "^C"`

But at my csh shell I don't need any of it, simply `rmdir ^C` already works for me.

Comment: In csh typing `rmdir ` followed by <ctrl>C works? Really?! I'd expect it to behave differently, namely aborting the `rmdir` command and returning you to the commandline.

Comment: It will indeed. See the accepted answer about how to enter a ^C character on the command line.